# Same password values comparison returns false cakephp

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I am trying to compare the input 'pass' with the 'pass' from the database. If it matches, the user will then proceed to the registration form.

Even though both passwords have the same value, I still get a false result with 'password is not correct' and a notice: Undifined index:pass.
I'm using Cakephp 2.8

This is the code I have now:

```
    public function checkCodeRespondent() {

     $password = $this->data['Respondent']['pass'];

      if (isset($password) && !empty($password))
      {

          $respondent = $this->findByPass($password);
          debug($respondent);

            if ($this->data['Respondent']['pass'] != $respondent['pass']) {


                print 'password is not correct';
            } else {
                print 'password is correct';
            }


      }
```

And this is the function to retrieve the data from database

```
    public function findByPass($pass) {

    $respondent = $this->Respondent->find('first', array('conditions' => array('pass' => $pass)));
    return $respondent;
}
```

Comment: No both are not hashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your password is not hashed just try :

```
 public function checkCodeRespondent() {
 $password = $this->data['Respondent']['pass'];
 $condition = array('Respondent.pass'=>$password);
 if($this->Respondent->hasAny($condition)){
 print 'password is correct';
        } else {
            print 'password is not correct';
        }
 }
```

You don't need multiple function at all..

Comment: Thx alot for this. It's working. So this only works when not hashed?

Comment: Of course not, This works for all time...I just mean if your password was hashed i would have added another condition too..

Comment: Just to be curious :) How would you add the condition? Maybe it will come in handy for another project

Comment: hasAny is function by cakephp and of course it is handy for so many cases like:  
              making email unique..or don't save duplicate data etc....You can also add multiple condition within has any...just like $condition = array('Respondent.pass'=>$password,'Respondent.name'=>'A');

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> `Undefined index 'pass'`

means an array is referencing a Key value that has not been set, so either `$this->data['Respondent']['pass']` value has not been set or `$respondent['pass']` has not been set. Check both and see which one is missing and then step back to find the cause of the missing data.

**Debug:**
What does a `print_r($this->data);` output? And what does `print_r($respondent);` output, are both of these arrays the shape you expect?

NB: Also because they're passwords:
Are either of these values hashed? If so, are *both* of them hashed?

Comment: Thx alot for your fast response :D You are right $respondent['pass'] has a value of null.

It is a little strange, because in $respondent the value is set. What am i missing?

Comment: @user2314339 ok does the `debug` function clear the variable value?

Comment: @user2314339 so the next stage is to check why `->findByPass($password)` is not returning a valid value

Comment: I can see the password in debug function. Only when i'm trying to set $respondent['pass'] the value changes to null

Comment: I'm such an idiot hahaha. 

Forgot 'Respondent'. He was looking in the wrong array....

$respondent['Respondent']['pass']; Now it's working. Thx alot for the help!

Comment: @user2314339 hahaha happens to the best of us, glad you found it. May be useful if you answer your own question to state that it was a typo type mistake `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo :)

This:

```
 if ($this->data['Respondent']['pass'] != $respondent['pass'])
```

Should be this:

```
 if ($this->data['Respondent']['pass'] != $respondent['Respondent']['pass'])
```

Now the comparison works like a charm